# Java regex pattern matches a string when i obtain string from System.in but not when declared

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text message from the phone that I want to extract the date it was sent on using regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    // this is the regex I input in the console [0-9]\Q/\E[0-9]\Q/\E[0-9] to match any date 
    //in the form dd/mm/yy

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter your regex: ");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter string to match: ");

    // the string I read from the console is in the form 
    // P67XDF9K7 confirmed you have received Ksh4,033.00 from 254723981091 on 7/9/14 at 6:45PM your new M-PESA balance is Ksh9,5033 M-PESA PIN YAKO SIRI YAKO

    String message = reader.readLine();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
    System.out.println(matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "no match found");
}
```

when i try the same in this program, I get an error that the string did not mat

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String regex = "[0-9]\\Q/\\E[0-9]\\Q/\\E[0-9]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String message = "P67XDF9K7 confirmed you have received Ksh4,033.00 from 254723981091 on 7/9/14 at 6:45PM your new M-PESA balance is Ksh9,5033 M-PESA PIN YAKO SIRI YAKO";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
    System.out.println(matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "no match found");
}
```

If I haven't typed the code wrongly, the first code matches the date correctly and prints out 7/9/14 but the second doesn't match the date. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: I doubt the first one prints `7/9/14` since it will only match `7/9/1`. Also, the example program works fine on my computer.

Comment: They both worked for me.  Although the regexp could be improved to match dates with multiple digits.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you need to quote the `/`? (i.e. you don't)

Comment: @Mena I don't work with regex too often so I just assumed `/` is a special character that needed to be quoted. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in your regex that there must be  two digits present at the last.

```
[0-9]{1,2}\\Q/\\E[0-9]{1,2}\\Q/\\E[0-9]{2}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gS3iY5/7)

```
String s = "P67XDF9K7 12/12/12 confirmed you have  received Ksh4,033.00 from 254723981091 on 7/9/14 at 6:45PM your new M-PE";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}\\Q/\\E[0-9]{1,2}\\Q/\\E[0-9]{2}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
12/12/12
7/9/14
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I was just about to test if something like 12/12/14 would work. How can I get double digits? really green in this area